# Outlook removes extra lines in email signature

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm creating an email signature in html. We mainly use outlook for mac and I don't face this issue when sending this signature from another mailclient.

In the preview window in my outlook signature "editor" everything looks fine, also in the mail itself the formatting is correct.
 Only when I click on send and view the mail in outlook the extra lines are gone.
 Also in every other mailclient the sent mail is messed up and the spacing got removed by outlook.

I've tested apple mail, send the same signature to myself, opened the mail in outlook and the formatting is completely fine as well.
 I assume that only outlook is the problem when I send with outlook.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this?
 The way I import the signature is to open it in a browser, highlight everything with `CMD + A` and paste it into the signature window of outlook with `CMD + V`. As I've seen it's only possible on windows to add the blank html by locating the signature file.

Simple example what I want to achieve:

```
<p>
  <span>Line 1</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>Line 2</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>Line 3</span>
</p>
```

My expected result and the result everywhere besides outlook:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

How outlook displays it after I sent it through outlook:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```